# BeautifulSoup beautifying an ugly process

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing the following HTML using beautifulSoup:

```
<div id="cpv_codes">
   <span>
        79000000 - Business services: law, marketing, consulting, recruitment, printing and security
        <br/>
        79632000 - Personnel-training services
        <br/>
        80000000 - Education and training services
        <br/>
        80511000 - Staff training services
        <br/>
        80530000 - Vocational training services
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to convert the contents into a list so that it can be put in a csv for later normalisation.

At the moment, I'm using a tortuously ugly process to hammer the data into shape and I'd very much like to write something more elegant. I'm sure that by using BS better I can extract the data in a list using one line, can anyone help me to clean up this code?

```
categories = tender_soup.find('div',{"id":"cpv_codes"}).findNext('span')
categories = unicode(categories) # converts tag output to a string
categories = categories.split('<br/>') # converts string to an array
categories = [category.replace('<span>', '') for category in categories] # removes '<span>' from items
categories = [category.replace('</span>', '') for category in categories] # removes '</span>' from items
categories = filter(None, categories) # filters out any empty items in the array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`NavigableString`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) class would help here:

```
from bs4 import NavigableString

span = tender_soup.find('div',{"id":"cpv_codes"}).findNext('span')
categories = [c.strip() for c in span.contents if isinstance(c, NavigableString)]
```

Now you have the list

```
[u'79000000 - Business services: law, marketing, consulting, recruitment, printing and security',
 u'79632000 - Personnel-training services',
 u'80000000 - Education and training services',
 u'80511000 - Staff training services',
 u'80530000 - Vocational training services']
```

Comment: Sébastien, that is a thing of beauty. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Sébastien, I'm trying to do the same thing with a different tag and I'm only getting the first row of the string returned as a single item in a list. Would the quotes be throwing out your original code?   `code`<dd class="multi_line">row1_string<br>row2_string<br>row3_string<br>row4_string<br>row5_string<br>row6_string<br/></br></br></br></br></br></dd>`code`

Comment: I used the same code, simply changing the `span` of course, and it worked for me. Since this html seems kinda broke, I may depend on the parser you used (I used the default parser on BeautifulSoup4).

Answer (score 0):

You might find `regular expression` useful.

```
import re
categories = tender_soup.find('div',{"id":"cpv_codes"}).findNext('span')
categories = [itm for itm in re.split(r'\s{2,}', categories.text) if itm]
```

From your data, the categories will be then like this,

```
[u'79000000 - Business services: law, marketing, consulting, recruitment, printing and security',
u'79632000 - Personnel-training services',
u'80000000 - Education and training services',
u'80511000 - Staff training services',
u'80530000 - Vocational training services']
```